# Is "To swim like a stone" considered a common idiom in use?

Tags: idiom-request

Are there any authentic idioms meaning the inability to swim?

I am not sure that the idiom "to swim like a stone' is widely used and even whether it's an idiom.

Comment: More usual is "swim like a rock".

Comment: No, Yulia, a person or thing sinks ***like a rock***. You either swim or don't and if you do, you might swim like a fish, that is, very well. I never heard swim like a rock in my life.

Comment: I think *swim like a stone/rock* are about the same for frequency, maybe **stone** leading a little. https://books.google.com/books?id=EuvqPkAq2bkC&pg=PA417&dq=%22swim+like+a+stone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-9tWesafUAhVl34MKHYhaBx4Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22swim%20like%20a%20stone%22&f=false or this: https://books.google.com/books?id=T1Q1AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT249&dq=%22swim+like+a+stone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd1KLksafUAhWr7IMKHU3nDkk4ChDoAQghMAA#v=onepage&q=%22swim%20like%20a%20stone%22&f=false

Answer (score 2):

There are some versions and all are considered Ok:

> To swim like a **rock**
>
> To swim like a **stone**
>
> To swim like a **brick**

Google shows most results for "to swim like a rock", and then in a big distance of results it's "to swim like a stone" and then not so far "to swim like a brick".

Another possibilities -less common but exist -for idioms are:

> To swim like a tailor's goose

[image]

(A Dictionary of Confusable Phrases. p.311)

Another one is:

> To swim like a axe

[image]

(A Book of Russian Idioms Illustrated By M. I. Dubrovin, P.212)

Comment: As a native English speaker, I have never heard of "swim like a tailor's goose" nor "swim like an axe" (and it's not listed in any good dictionaries, not even OED) and wouldn't know what you meant. These two are Russian idioms, not English idioms.